Подскажите как загружать репозитории из гитхаба в гугл-колаб
я новичек в гугл-колаб, пытаюсь клонировать в гугл-колаб репозиторий по этой команде
git clone https://github.com/demining/CryptoDeepTools.git
но у меня выскакивает синтаксичиская ошибка.
Подскажите что я делаю не так или ткните мой носик в тему где об этом можно узнать подробнее:)

Какая синтаксическая ошибка? Контр-ответ: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone и почему бы и нет

Ну нельзя просто сказать, что у вас возникает синтаксическая ошибка, и не привести её

Нашёл ответ вам (да, я заморочился) — проблема и решение с enSO
